# New desktop build giving electric shock on touching it

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power, desktop-computer, case

I got a new desktop system. It's giving electric shock if I touch the system cabinet case. On checking with electric tester, it's led was glowing too.

I had plugged it into a two pin plug ( without earth) since it was the same plug that I had my old desktop plugged into and it was working fine (no shocks). 
I then reversed the polarity of the plug.. it lessened the electric intensity but current was still there when testing with tester. 
I then connected the new desktop system to 3 pin plug ( with earth/ground) and it was no longer giving any current/shock when touching the cabinet.

My question is: How can I make sure that the current is not leaking into the earth from new system and everything is fine ( no shorts, leakage of current, faulty PSU/motherboard or any wire touching the cabinet case etc). Also why my old desktop is not giving shock on the same two pin plug?

Would any new system give shock if connected to two pin? ( connecting to 3 pin is mandatory?)

Relevant Specs: Antec GX900 cabinet, Antec VP500PC 500 watts PSU, Asus motherboard H270, I3 processor.

Thanks

Comment: Connect the pc to ground is how to prevent this as your tests have proven

Comment: So will a system necessarily give a shock if not connected to 3 pin?

Comment: Provided your wiring (house/apartment) is correct.

Comment: 1. You wired it wrong, check again. 2. plugging a non-double-insulated appliance into an unearthed socket is utter madness [I come from a country where that's not even possible or legal]

Comment: Get a plug with earth. If your home power trips, get an electrician to check.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek .. I have already connected the system to 3 pin plug and there is no tripping but does that mean there is no leakage of current from PSU or other parts?

Answer (score -1):

The third pin is what is called as the Earthing/Grounding Pin. Leakage currents should be handled in any electrical appliance or it will try to look out for other exit points to discharge. Earthing Pin is the solution to handle leakage currents, provided that your entire house is grounded.